# Kdump doesn't executed on Kernel Panic

Tags: crash-dumps

I'am trying to get kdump work an a Debian Squeeze.
I've made a dump kernel with this config 
[.config](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y0m72g8xrndy68u/.config)

The normal Kernel gets started in grub with the option `crashkernel=128M`
kdump tells me that the dump kernel is loaded and ready for dumping.

The kexec command that is executed by kdump also seems to work.

```
kexec -p --command-line="BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-kdump root=UUID=ee9dbc96-599a-4c55-b20c-2bc2b2301581 rw 1 irqpoll maxcpus=1 reset_devices" --initrd=/boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-kdump /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-kdump
```

If i use -f instead of -p the dump kernel is loaded.

But when i trigger a crashdump with sysrq nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable the config macro CONFIG_KEXEC? Can you add prints at the panic() function in the kernel/panic.c file and check?